# perl regex remove anything between pairs of quotes

Tags: regex, perl, quotes

I have a string and I would like to remove any thing that appears in between a pair quotes and just replace it with the two quotes. Right now I have:

```
$string =~ s/'.*?'/''/g;
```

However, this doesn't cover the case where there are quotes within a string, such as:

```
$string = "'This is Joe\'s car'";
```

I would like for this to be `"''"`, but it really ends up being `"''s car'"`

Is there anyway to remove everything between the outermost pair of quotes? Thanks!

Comment: This is not a trivial task. What if there's a `\\'s` in the string? What about `\\\'s`?

Answer (score 2):

You asked for it by making the regex non-greedy.  Saying:

```
$string =~ s/'.*'/''/g;
```

should produce the expected results.

Comment: but what if my string can have multiple pairs of quoted items? I'm sorry, I guess I should've mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 2):

As has already been stated, this is not a trivial task.  Unless there are explicit blackslashes in the string to indicate that a quote is not meant to be part of a balanced pair, there will be no direct way to determine where balanced pairs lie.  It would require programming the English language rules behind the use of single quotes to do this, and even then there would likely be edge cases.

One method that might get closer is if you used negative lookahead and look behind assertions to require that the start quote not be preceeded by a word character, and the end quote not be followed by one.  However, even this requirement would fail on plural possessives as demonstrated by the last example in the following script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp(my $src = $_);
    chomp(my $test = <DATA>);

    $src =~ s/(?<!\w)'(.*?)'(?!\w)/'<$1>'/g;

    print ($src eq $test ? 'matches  - ' : 'no match - ');
    print $src, "\n";
}


__DATA__
This is just a normal sentence.
This is just a normal sentence.
'This is Joe's car'
'<This is Joe's car>'
She said, "He said, 'Hurry up.'"
She said, "He said, '<Hurry up.>'"
This is 'special.'  That is also 'special.'
This is '<special.>'  That is also '<special.>'
'These are players' cars'
'<These are players' cars>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
$string =~ s/'.*?(?<!\\)'/''/g;
```

However this will not work for input `hey 'joe \'car`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the built-in module `Text::Balanced` and its `extract_delimited()` function. In list context it returns either the text between quotes, the prefix and the reminder, so you can check them and remove those parts to skip:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Balanced qw<extract_delimited>;

my $result;

my $string = "Before quotes 'This is Joe\\'s car' After quotes 'Last content' End";

while ( my @r = extract_delimited($string, q|'|, q|[^']*|) ) { 
    $result .= $r[-1] || ''; 
    if ( ! defined $r[0] ) { 
        $result .= $r[1];
        last 
    }   
    else {
        $result .= "''";
    }   
    $string = $r[1];
}

printf qq|%s\n|, $result;
```

Note that I used a double backslash to escape a single quote because `perl` escapes all single quotes by itself before processing it. Also note that an escaped single quote at the beginning, like:

```
my $string = "Before \\'quotes 'This is Joe\\'s car';
```

won't work either. It's weird, I know, but it could work in most simple cases. Just give it a try.

Run the test like:

```
perl script.pl
```

That yields:

```
Before quotes '' After quotes '' End
```